# How to use dependency injection in enterprise projects

Tags: c#, architecture, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Imagine you have an application with several hundreds of classes implementing dozens of "high level" interfaces (meaning component level). Is there a recommend way of doing dependecy injection (like with unity). Should there be a "general container" that can be used for bootstrapping, accessible as a Singleton? Should a container be passed around, where all instances can RegisterInstance? Should everything be done by RegisterType somewhere in the startup? How can the container be made accessible when needed. Constructor injection seems false, controverse of being the standard way, you have to pass down interfaces from a component level to the very down where it is used right on startup, or a reference is hold ending up in a "know where you live" antipattern. 
And: having a container "available" may bring developers to the idea of resolving server components in client context. how to avoid that?

Any discussion welcome!

---

**edit for clarification**

I figured out a somewhat realworld example to have a better picture of what problems i see.

lets imagine the application is a hifi system.
the system has cd player (integrated in a cd-rack) and 
an usb port (integrated in an usb rack) to play music from.

now, the cd player and the usb port shall be able to play mp3 music.

i have an mp3 decoder somewhere around, which is injectable.

now i start the hifi system. there is no cd inserted yet and
no usb stick pluged in. i do not need a mp3 decoder now.

but with constructor injection, i have to already inject 
the dependency into the cd rack and the usb rack.

what if i never insert a mp3 cd or an mp3 usb stick?

shall i hold an reference in the cd rack, so when an mp3 cd 
is inserted, i have a decorder on hand? (seems wrong to me)

the decoder is needed in a subsystem of the cd rack, which
is only started if a mp3 gets inserted. now i have no container
in the cd rack, what about constructor injection here?

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't matter whether you're developing an "enterprise" application or a "non-enterprise" application. It's the same ideas all around. Constructor Injection is quite nice when you have DI that can resolve those dependencies automatically for you. Plus, it lends itself to naturally growing into an application because you can manually wire up the dependencies before going full blown DI.

Comment: i wanted to emphasize that it shall work with bigger scenarios in real world projects. enterprise was the term i chose, as in enterprise application architecture. in smaller applications, every way may be right.

Comment: No way is "wrong." There's just differing degrees of appropriateness. It depends in part on the project in question and, also to a large extent, the developer's personal preferences. The only scenario I can imagine where "enterprise" (in your sense of meaning large) applications may have a different need is in the performance of the underlying DI implementation. But that's largely an implementation detail dependent on whatever tool you're using for the DI. You can write a DI container that performs extremely well or poorly.

Comment: I think one of the largest things is whether you're developing this application from the ground up or if you're tacking this onto an existing application. If the latter, it may be more natural for you to refactor your code to make use of manual constructor injection then add something like Ninject, AutoFac, Unity, etc. that can automatically wire up that construction hierarchy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is a design pattern that does not require a container. The DI pattern states:

> Dependency injection is a software design pattern that allows a choice of component to be made at run-time rather than compile time

Take for example Guice (java dependency injection framework), in Java Guice is a DI framework but it is not a container itself.

Most of the DI tools in .Net are actually containers, so you need to populate the container in order to be able to inject the dependency

I do not like the idea to have to register every component every time in a container, I simply hate that. There are several tools that help you auto register components based on conventions, I do not use Unity, but I can point you for example to [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) or [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

I am actually writing a [small utility](https://github.com/jupaol/NAutoRegister) to auto register components based on conventions using practically any DI tool, it is still in dev phase

About your questions:

> Should there be a "general container" that can be used for bootstrapping, accessible as a Singleton?

The answer is yes, (there's a tool to abstract the DI tool used, it is called [ServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/)) that's how DI tools work, there is a static container available to the application, however, it is not recommended to use it inside the domain objects to create instances, that's considered an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)

BTW I have found this tool really useful to register components at runtime:

http://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/

> Should a container be passed around, where all instances can RegisterInstance?

No. that would violate the [law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). If you decide to use a container is better to register the components when the application starts

> How can the container be made accessible when needed

Well using the Common Service Locator you could use it anywhere in your application, but like I said, it is not recommended to use it inside the domain objects to create the required instances, instead, inject the objects in the constructor of the object and let the DI tool to automatically inject the correct instance.

Now based on this:

> Constructor injection seems false, controverse of being the standard way, you have to pass down interfaces from a component level to the very down where it is used right on startup, or a reference is hold ending up in a "know where you live" antipattern

Makes me think that you are not writing unit tests **heavily** for your application which is bad. So my suggestion is, before choosing between which DI tool you are going to use, or before taking all the answers you get to this question into consideration, refer to the following links which are focus on one thing: **Write clean testable code**, this is by far the best source you could get to answer yourself your own question

Clean Code talks:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w&feature=player_embedded
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0&feature=player_embedded

Articles

- http://misko.hevery.com/2010/05/26/do-it-yourself-dependency-injection/
- http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/
- Previous link in PDF http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf

The following links are **super highly recommended**

http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/

http://www.loosecouplings.com/2011/01/how-to-write-testable-code-overview.html

Comment: Unity is the container based solution currently in use. lets consider Unity to be set, there are lots of ways to use it, all have some advantages, but i can't find any best pratices on that best practices (prism) usage.

Comment: I am not an expert using Unity, but I remember you need to register components in the container, my suggestion is do it at startup and take a look at these tools: http://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/ and http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/ both have plugins for Unity

Comment: i clearly do not want to pass over components needed in constructor, as it blocks me from setting up components as they are needed. but everything else seems to end up in service locator antipattern. need to think about that.

Comment: I think the last two links I posted are exactly what you need

Comment: There is no problem with testable code (mocking is already in place) and no problem with the distinction between injectable and newable objects. I want to know how to handle the injectables correctly. And of course, if there are any good approved designs to setup DI.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is the Composition Root pattern, you set up your dependencies as soon as possible, Main() in desktop, global.asax/app_start in web. Then, rely on constructor injection as this makes your dependencies clear.

However, you still need something to actually RESOLVE dependencies. There are at least two approaches known to me.

First one consist in using the Service Locator (which is almost equal to making the container a singleton). This is considered an antipattern for a lot of people, however it just works great. Whenever you need a service, you ask your container for it:

```
 ... business code...
 var service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMyService>();
 service.Foo();
```

Service Locator just uses a container you set up in the Composition Root.

Another approach consist in relying on object factories available as singletons with the container injected into them:

```
 var service = IMyServiceFactory.Instance.CreateService();
```

The trick is that implementation of the factory uses the container internally to resolve the service. However, this approach, with an additional factory layer, makes your business code **independent** and **unaware** of the IoC! You are free to completely redesign the factories to **not to use** IoC internally and still maintain every single line of business code.

In other words, it's just a trick then to hide the container/locator behind a factory layer.

While tempted to use the former approach (rely directly on the locator) I prefer the latter. It just feels cleaner.

I wonder if there are other viable alternatives here.

Comment: Service locator is seen as an antipattern here. But with an additional factory layer, you can factor out DI as you already stated. Nice answer so, need to think about that.

Comment: The factory approach seem to be overlooked often. Most people insist that Service Locator is an antipattern but the only answer they have is the Composition Root. But you just can't compose EVERYTHING at the beginning and have everything exposed as a singleton. To me, factories are the only way to abstract the creation so that IoC can be isolated and kept under control.

Comment: Composition root does not look that bad. Need to investigate what that ConfigureContainer is about. Keeping IoC under control is clearly what i'm thinking about. Thank you!

Comment: after some reading i think injecting factories is the right way to go

Comment: Yep, Composition Root plus custom factories with injected container.

Comment: Okay, this is the way to go. Mark Seemann has some really good articles here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx and the other one http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx    THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: He also mentions using factories in his book for one specific example of a custom MVC controller factory where controllers have explicit, constructor injected, dependencies. However, the idea of factories should of course be expanded to other areas.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: You are right that you can't always compose the complete dependency graph at the start and factories are often a good solution to this problem. However, your solution consists of a static factory (`Factory.Instance`), which is bad for several reasons. First of all it makes it hard to unit test that code. Think for instance about what you need to do getting this running in MSTest, a test runner that runs tests in parallel (which never should be a problem). ...

Comment: ... Another short come is that it will be unclear from looking at the constructor of classes in the system, that they actually make use of this factory. Code becomes harder to follow and it becomes easier to violate the Single Responsibility Principle. The solution to all of this, is to inject a factory into consumers, instead of letting consumers refer to `Factory.Instance.Create()`. By using an interface, you can define the implementation of this factory in the composition root, and you can inject the container into this implementation without using the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Comment: @Steven: what is unclear to me is the last sentence. Ok, you can register an implementation of the factory to the factory interface. But how on earth are you going to RESOLVE the dependency without having the container in the consumer class? In my idea, the factory uses the container INTERNALLY so that it can resolve the service dependency to any implementation you have registered. But the factory itself is never described by an interface because the implementation is always fixed. Take a look at the implementation of the controller factory in Mark Seemann's book - his factory is fixed.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: I haven't got Mark's book on me right now (I'll take a peek at this when I get home), but Mark never advices to use a singleton pattern in his book. The idea however is simple. 1. Define an `interface IMyServiceFactory` in the application. 2. Let consumers depend on `IMyServiceFactory`. 3. Create an `class MyServiceFactoryImpl : IMyServiceFactory` in the composition root that uses the `Container` to resolve and return implementations (you can use ctor injection to pass the container in). 4. Bind the `IMyServiceFactory` to the `MyServiceFactoryImpl` in the container. 5. Done.

Comment: @Steven: and then what if you need the factory in your business code? How are you supposed to get the instance? There are only two options, either you have the container instance (so that you can resolve using the instance) or you have the factory singleton (so you don't need the container). I still don't see any other options. Can you show a line of a client code which resolves the factory instance and follows your approach?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: "what if you need the factory in your business code?". You won't. You just need the interface in your code and the implementation in your composition root. And if you need it in your app, i.e. because it has a lot of logic, you are probably violating the Single Responsibility Principle, which means you should abstract that logic to its own service and inject that into the factory implementation. I can't really show you any code in these comments. We can move this discussion to a new SO question (if can come up with a good question), or if you which, you can mail me directly.

Comment: @Steven: it is not about interfaces/implementations but about instances. In an instance of your factory/service is available in the composition root, how (for example) you are going to pass it to asp.net web forms page? Note that the example is carefully picked up: in web.forms you can't alter the way page instances are created.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Yes, Web Forms is a problem (compared to ASP.NET MVC). You will need to revert to Service Locator in Web Forms; there is no real good alternative. You can't let the container create Page and UserControl instances. But that doesn't mean that you should just abandon dependency injection for the complete application. Only use Service Locator inside the Page and UserControl constructors (see [this example](bit.ly/LXndfn)). I see no reason for using the Singleton pattern for your factories in that case (except perhaps when you are refactoring a legacy app). Does this make sense?

Comment: @Steven: ok. I think the confusion is gone now. It's just a matter of preferring one style over the other. My approach with isolating locator within static factories is just to not to rely too much on the locator (or rather - to isolate it to only specific places where it can be easily found and probably refactored). For a moment I just thought that you have a magic spell not known to me for some reason and you can somehow resolve instances in such specific contexts. Regards.

Comment: As you can see in [me example](http://bit.ly/LXndfn), I hide the container behind a `GetInstance` method in ASP.NET Web Forms apps. This to prevent direct exposure to the container and allow easy refactoring. I think we're on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

> Should a container be passed around

No, since this leads to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

> where all instances can RegisterInstance

Services should be registered in the start-up path of the application, not by types themselves. When you have multiple applications (such as web app, web service, WPF client), there will often be a common bootstrapper project that wires all services together for shared layers (but each application will still have its unique wiring, since no application behaves the same).

> Should everything be done by RegisterType somewhere in the startup

Yes, you should wire everything up at start-up.

> How can the container be made accessible when needed.

You shouldn't. The application should be oblivious to the use of a container (if any container is used, since this is optional). If you don't do this, you will make a lot of things much harder, such as testing. You can however, inject the container in types that are defined in the startup path of the application (a.k.a. the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx)). This way the application keeps clean from knowing anything about the container.

> Constructor injection seems false, controverse of being the standard way

Constructor injection is the **prefered** way of injecting dependencies. However, it can be challanging to refactor an existing application towards constructor injection. In **rare* circumstances where constructor injection doesn't work, you can revert to property injection, or when it is impossible to build up the complete object graph, you can inject a factory. When the factory implementation is part of the composition root, you can let it depend on the container.

A pattern I found very useful, that can be built on top of the Dependency Injection pattern and the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) design principles, is the [command / handler pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). I found this a useful pattern in smaller apps, but it will shine when applications get big, such as enterprise applications.

Comment: oh yes, i love the command pattern, especially in reactor. at the moment i think a factory in the composition root is the way to go, and constructor inject it into my domain. thany you very much for your answer!

Comment: Especially take a look at the model that [separates commands (DTO) from handlers (behavior)](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91), which allows you to apply decorators to those handlers. This brings great testability and great flexibility without initial complexity. But note that Unity can't handle generic decorators easily. You might want to switch to a different DI container, when you are applying this pattern.

Comment: But don't let the DI container lead you, but pick the container based on your architecture. Here is a recent (and good) quote from Mark Seemann: [First rule of DI: first you architect your API/App, only then do you worry about how to fit a DI Container to it. Never the other way around](https://twitter.com/ploeh/status/212901026150350848)

Comment: thank you! mark seemann seems to be an absulote pro concerning DI.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: Yes, he is. I am just a humble [number four](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dependency-injection/topusers) :=).

Comment: Sorry, I clearly did not want to discourage you. I love your answer, as it completly satisfies all of my questions, and i love the concept of the command pattern (and i use in all of my projects heavily) and i already love your blog :D

Answer (score 1):

> now i start the hifi system. there is no cd inserted yet and no usb
>   stick pluged in. i do not need a mp3 decoder now.

This seems like a perfect fit for **Setter injection** (=property injection in C#). Use a NeutralDecoder or NullDecoder as a default and inject an Mp3Decoder when you need it. You can do it by hand or using a DI container and conditional/late binding.

http://blog.springsource.com/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/

> We usually advise people to use constructor injection for all
>   *mandatory collaborators* and setter injection for all other properties.

Comment: Property injection or Setter injection is the solution of a part of the problems here. thank you for your valuable answer!